# how to consolidate multiple asynchronous processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, foreach, callback

These are my code.

```
var myOrderIds = req.user.orders; // array of order document's ObjectId
var myReserv = []; // I want to put specific order into myRerv[] by mongoose findOne()

var showReservList = function(oids, callback) {
    oids.forEach(function(oid) {
        database.OrderModel.findOne({'_id' : oid, 'isCompleted' : false},function(err, docs) {
             callback(docs);
        });
    });
}

showReservList(myOrderIds, function (res) {
    myReserv.push(res);
});

console.log(myReserv); // empty
```

The problem is myReserv[] is empty. 
I wonder how to consolidate multiple asynchronous processes and not just handle the completion of a single one. (This is the common case.)
`console.log(myReserv)` is executed faster than `myRserv.push(res)`. I want to delay `console.log(myRresrv)` until `myRserv.push(res)` finishes to work.

Comment: Show your attempt with Promises, because they do work if used correctly.

Comment: This is a synchronicty issue. Synchonous code (like `console.log()`) will always execute before asynchronous code completes. I assume your `findOne()` method returns a promise, thus is asynchronous.

Comment: `myReserv` isn't undefined. It's explicitely an empty array at the moment it's being logged.

Comment: IMO, the 'duplicate' mark on this question is improper considering how the bigger part of this issue concerns how to consolidate multiple asynchronous processes and not just handle the completion of a single one (which is the case with the linked question)

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Thank you! I edited my question properly.